# how to update ajax updatepanel which it is located outside of the iframe in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, updatepanel

I have a *ASPX* file which contains an update panel and *iframe*.
After some processes in the *iframe* I'm going to update some values outside of the
iframe (inside the update panel).

How can I update, update panel from  inside the *iframe*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a code that trigger the UpdatePanel using javascript. You can do that by adding a hidden button inside the UpdatePanel as:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <asp:Button ID="DoUpdate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</div>
```

and now, from the iframe you can find this button and run the click as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.parent.document.getElementById('DoUpdate').click();
<script>
```

I like to point here the `ClientIDMode="Static"` that must be static because from iframe we cant know find the rendered id of this button, so we make it static to not let it change, and the `window.parent.` that is going to search the window that's contains the iframe, the parent window of the iframe